# Authentication on self-hosted WCF-Rest service

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, authentication, nancy

I'm creating a .Net (C#) application which has a web-interface, which is reachable from the local network of the user. Of course, the user can choose to make the web-interface accessible from the outside (internet) too.

The web-interface is an SPA (Single Page Application). There's a Rest-interface for the website and a WCF interface, so other software can easily interact with my application. Both are self-hosted.

The website itself (the HTML page(s)) is self-hosted with [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/).

The operationcontracts for WCF and Rest look like this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public string GetStuff()
    {
        return "Stuff";
    }
```

The WCF/Rest-service is started like this:

```
// Create the ServiceHost.
apiHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceClass), Address);

apiHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
ServiceEndpoint restEndpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(ServiceClass)), new WebHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(RestAddress));
restEndpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

apiHost.AddServiceEndpoint(restEndpoint);
```

Now I would like to add a login to the website and the Rest-service (login to the WCF service will be added later). But whenever I try methods explained on the internet, something doesn't work. For example I tried [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304877/WCF-REST-4-0-Authorization-with-Form-Based-Authent), but then I can't access HttpContext.Current.User.Identity because the current HttpContext is empty.

Can anyone explain me how I can add authentication to my implementation, or at least point me in the right direction?
There are a lot of methods in the ServiceContract, so I would prefer not to do some manual checks in each method. But if there's no other way, I can maybe get something to work with PostSharp to add some authentication-code to each method.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to turn on aspNetCompabitilityEnabled=”true" in the web.config for HttpContext.Current to return something. Also set RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required on the service.